# How is a fragment instantiated from XML config?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android dev and am having a lot of trouble understanding the flow of things in the xml config file for each activity. I am trying to use fragments in an activity but dont exactly understand how it is instantiated. Does the android:id=@+id/.... actually instantiate the fragment? Is it the equivalent of calling a TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment() in the code? If anyone can clarify this or point me to a good resource explaining this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S. IS that what the +id does in general? Instantiate the components (as in new...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Android resources, which are already defined in Android system, you can access it with `@android:id/..` while to access resources that you have defined/created in your project, you have to use `@id/..`

If we use `android:id="@id/layout_item_id"` it doesn't work. instead `@+id/` works so what's the difference here.

well, it depends on the context, when you're using the XML attribute of `android:id`, then you're specifying a new id, and are instructing the parser (or call it the builder) to create a new entry in `R.java`, thus you have to include a `+ sign`.

While in the other case, like `android:layout_below="@id/myTextView"` , you're referring to an id that has already been created, so parser links this to the already created id in `R.java`

```
    Is it the equivalent of calling a TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment() in the code?
```

Defining `ids` in xml doesn't same as the initializing the `Fragments`.

You can define/initialize the Fragment in two way as below:

**1) Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.**
In this case, you can specify layout properties for the fragment as if it were a view. For example, here's the layout file for an activity with two fragments:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

The `android:name` attribute in the `<fragment>` specifies the Fragment class to instantiate in the layout.
When the system creates this activity layout, it instantiates each fragment specified in the layout and calls the `onCreateView()` method for each one, to retrieve each fragment's layout. The system inserts the View returned by the fragment directly in place of the  element.

**2) Programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.**

At any time while your activity is running, you can add fragments to your activity layout. You simply need to specify a ViewGroup in which to place the fragment.
To make fragment transactions in your activity (such as add, remove, or replace a fragment), you must use APIs from `FragmentTransaction`. You can get an instance of `FragmentTransaction` from your Activity like this:

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

You can then add a fragment using the `add()` method, specifying the fragment to add and the view in which to insert it. For example:

```
   ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

For more details check  [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I saw the calls being made to the Fragment's OnCreateView() but wasnt sure that it was the xml doing it after i called the setContentView to load the layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two different ways to instantiate a fragment:

1. Put in your layout fragment tag like
2. Put in your layout FrameLayout

In the first case (1.) your fragment is static it means you cant change it at runtime while using framelayout you can change it using for example:

```
Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fl1, f2);
ft.commit();
```

In Android +id just means you are adding a new id, that's all it doesn't instantiate anything. @+id/... in contrast to @id/... that means you are refering to an existing id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML to create a Fragments as part of your application's layout. That will allow you to better modularize your code and more easily adjust your user interface to the screen it is running on. Take a look at this example:

```
<!-- fragment_layout.xml -->
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment 
        class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I the above example **class** attribute defines the Fragment class from where the Fragment is instantiated in this case it's TitlesFragment class.

So in your activity install a layout in a standard way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
}
```

And TitlesFragment class:

```
public static class TitlesFragment extends Fragment {

// Implementation of your fragment class
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For more information check documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Basicly when you create a `View` or a `Layout` for that matter in your `XML` file, what you actually doing is to save your self a lot of code lines to create the same `View` or `Layout` in code. The reason is that this `XML` is latter will be translated into code using a `LayoutInflator`. (this will happen when you set this `View` as `setContentView()` of your `Activity`).

Same thing goes with the fragments you define in your XML layout file.